# Are Boost header libraries installed by default in Debian Squeeze?

Tags: boost, debian

I recently installed Debian Squeeze on my machine with C++ programming practice as one of the main goals. I use Boost libraries regularly in my projects. On OS-X and Windows, I had to manually install Boost header libraries prior to using them. However, regarding Linux, the front page of the Boost website [mentions](http://www.boost.org/)

> Popular Linux and Unix distributions such as Fedora, Debian, and NetBSD include pre-built Boost packages.

I use mainly the header libraries, not pre-built packages for my current projects. So my question is: Are the header libraries installed by default anywhere on Debian or do I have to install them? I have already looked in /usr/include and it doesn't seem to have any Boost directory. I have googled as well as looked up related discussions on SO, but didn't get a clear answer to my question. If I do have to install the header libraries, is there an 'apt-get' way of doing it or I simply untar and place in a convenient location (/usr/local/include) ?

Second, if I need to manually place the boost headers (say in /usr/local/include/), should the version of the headers match with the pre-installed packages for compatibility with any potential future projects which use both the binaties (libboost-*) and header files?

I am fairly new to programming on a Linux platform. Although, I can make things work using patch-and-match (and googling), I am looking for guidance on long term best practices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying a GNU/Linux distribution "includes" a package such as Boost doesn't mean it is installed automatically, it means the package is *available* for installation, using your system's package management tool.  The package might be tailored for your distribution, so it integrates well with the rest of the OS, or it might just be identical to the upstream version and the benefit is just that it's already built for you and convenient to install from within the OS.

There is tons of documentation on Debian's package mgt tools:

http://wiki.debian.org/PackageManagement

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html

So yes, you want to `apt-get` (or the equivalent with another of Debian's tools) to install Boost in `/usr/include`, that will be much easier than manually installing them.  If you later decide to install Boost manually, keep that installation entirely separate from the system packages, so the libraries and headers from the newer version don't conflict with the system packages.  If it's a single-user machine and you don't need the packages to be available to other users on the machine then you can just install them in your home directory, rather than `/usr/local/` (which requires superuser access, and you should do as little as possible as the root user)